# sql new column by delimiter with order ID

Tags: mysql, sql, delimiter

Hi this maybe a simple one but I need help specifically for MYsql

I have the data in one column lets call the column WORK 1,2,3,5,2 (these values are sometimes longer and shorter or more values are present e.g 12,15,11,15,16,143)

I need these to be put into 1 new column for each delimiter and have an ID for the order presented. e.g output

[image]

Comment: You mean you have values 1,2,3,5,2 present in a single cell and you have to split it as rows [considering the delimiter]. Further add a row number to it?

Comment: Yes thats what I'm tying to say

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using

Comment: SQL via phpmyadmin on webserver

Comment: wow ... so you decided to repost it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER()
  OVER (ORDER BY WORK) AS Row,
  RIGHT(LEFT(T.WORK, Number - 1),
  CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(LEFT(',' + T.WORK, Number - 1)))) AS a
FROM master..spt_values,
     <YOUR_TABLENAME> T
WHERE Type = 'P'
AND Number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(T.WORK) + 1
AND (SUBSTRING(T.WORK, Number, 1) = ','
OR SUBSTRING(T.WORK, Number, 1) = '')) AS A
```

Comment: Im getting function row number doesn't exist, i also tried this on mysql workbench

Comment: Works with MS SQL. Sorry not familiar with MYSQL

Comment: I guess all other statements would work. Just look for an alternative to row_number function in mysql

Comment: the charindex or len isnt recognized either so its a no go on this one